Selecting rows in specified order for each value from chosen colum
I'm trying to find a solution for my problem using MS SQL Server:
Table 1:



Column A




Value1


Value2


Value3



For above values from column A, I'm trying to "SELECT UNION" data from different tables -
(a,b,c represents few columns with data).
Problem is that my query output looks like this:



Col
Col2




a
Value1


a
Value2


a
Value3


b
Value1


b
Value2


b
Value3


c
Value1


c
Value2


c
Value3



And I want it to look like this:



Col
Col2




a
Value1


b
Value1


c
Value1


a
Value2


b
Value2


c
Value2


a
Value3


b
Value3


c
Value3



What can I do to output rows in a certain order for each value as in above example?
Maybe there is some built in option from Transact SQL to manipulate with order like that? Can I solve it with case() function?

Could you please provide the query you have attempted so far ?

Have you tried with ORDER BY Col2?

What's wrong with the appropriately named ORDER BY Clause?

You want to order by two columns: first by col2 and then by col. You can specify multiple columns in the ORDER BY clause to achieve this:
ORDER BY col2, col

